# Cordova FrameLayout overlaps in WebView

Tags: android, cordova, webview, resize, android-framelayout

I have a very annoying issue using a CodeBar scanner (git URL: https://github.com/tjwoon/csZBar).

I'm trying to resize the native layout wich the plugin creates, but even when I've done and adding "color.transparent" to the layout background, it keeps showing a black background hidding the WebView.

Actually I'm working with Cordova, developing a Managment APP which is using CB scanner and I want to "draw" the Scaner view over my webView, I know that is not possible draw a layout inside a webview so I've tried to resize the scan layout to overlap the WebView, and... as a result I've a black background... I would Upload some screens but since I've no 10 of reputation I cannot.. I would appreciate any help..

What I'm asking is: There is any way to make my Framelayout background compleatly transparent and show the webview behind the FrameLayout?

PD: I'm so sorry for my english mistakes..

Thank you!

EDIT:

// Add preview SurfaceView to the screen

```
 FrameLayout scannerView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(getResourceId("id/csZbarScannerView"));
    scannerView.addView(scannerSurface);

    scannerView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

findViewById(getResourceId("id/csZbarScannerTitle")).bringToFront();
findViewById(getResourceId("id/csZbarScannerInstructions")).bringToFront();        
findViewById(getResourceId("id/csZbarScannerSightContainer")).bringToFront();
findViewById(getResourceId("id/csZbarScannerSight")).bringToFront();
scannerView.requestLayout();
scannerView.invalidate();
```

this is Java code which the plugin is adding the surfaceView to the layout.
And this is how the Mobile looks like:
[image]

Comment: Upvoted so you can improve your question with some pictures and your code.

Comment: You have 11. :) I forgot you only get +5 for a question upvote, but someone else has upvoted as well.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Im getting the same issue